# Writing custom data-source or plugin to load Google My Maps data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, data-source

My goal is quite straightforward: display maps created and mantained in Google My Maps as a layer in QGIS.

The way I thought about doing this is the following:

1. Write a Python script that acts as some sort of server;
2. Get this server script to fetch data from Google My Maps (as KML) and serve this data somehow to QGIS, most probably using WFS API or similar;
3. Add the server address (something like `http://localhost:1234` I guess) as a readonly layer in QGIS.

Then, I could edit my maps using Google My Maps, but would be able to keep displaying their current state in QGIS.

So my questions are:

1. Does this scenario make sense? Is this a viable thing to do?
2. Is this "webserver" approach the best one? Should I be aiming at writing some sort of plugin instead?
3. Is it something that has already been done before?